# Watermark combined with no page numbering in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, watermark

UPDATED 20190319
I am using the command `\pagenumbering{gobble}` in order to suppress the page numbering in the table of contents (I only want to show the titles). The problem is that it does indeed suppress the page numbers in the ToC, but I now only see the DRAFT watermark on the ToC page, and the DRAFT watermark disappeared from all the following pages. As soon as I delete the line `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, the DRAFT watermark is visible again on all the pages, but I have page numbering in the ToC.

How can I bypass this problem, and have simultaneously the DRAFT watermark on all pages and page numbering suppression in the ToC (titles only)?

Here is my code

```
\documentclass[10pt, a3paper]{article}
\newcommand{\projecttitle}{Example}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
a3paper,
left=23mm,
top=15mm,
right=10mm,
bottom=15mm,
headheight=38pt,
includeheadfoot,
showframe=false
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\scalebox{20}{\tikz[color=gray!1000,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}}
\newwatermark*[allpages,angle=45]{\usebox\mybox}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents \thispagestyle{fancy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\parbox{\linewidth}{\section{Section 1}}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{any_pdf_image.pdf}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\parbox{\linewidth}{\section{Section 2}}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{any_pdf_image.pdf}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\parbox{\linewidth}{\section{Section 3}}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{any_pdf_image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please provide a full but minimal examples for others to test. This is a lot easier than trying to use just your sniplet and try to guess from there. For example where does `\newwatermark` come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue using the 'background' package. Thank you all for trying to help
All I did was:

```
\usepackage[pages=all]{background} % in the preamble
..............

\backgroundsetup{contents={DRAFT}, color=gray!1000, opacity=0.3, angle=45, scale=23} % right before \begin{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just add the water mark with `eso-pic`, there is no such problem. (I changed the appearance of the watermark to make it more visible but you can easily change it back.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[gray,opacity=0.3,scale=8,font=\sffamily,rotate=45] at (current page.center){DRAFT};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\foreach \X in {1,...,20}
{\section{Section \X}
\lipsum[\X]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think I was clear enough. Here is a small script I prepared

Comment: @Vlad My solution works with your script, too, except that I do not have the your graphics files. If you want to have something based on your solution, make it compilable first.

Comment: It is compilable. There are some warnings on the way but I confirm that the pdf gets built. Please try to run in non stop mode from cmd such: in the right location> pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode filename.tex

Comment: @Vlad It may be compilable on *your* machine because you have `E:/download.pdf` which most users won't have. Please provide an example that can be compiled on a generic machine, not just on yours.

Comment: Regarding the file download.pdf, I can't upload it here, but any pdf format image with that name can be used.. I know it would be nice if I uploaded a fully compilable script but I just couldn't  manage to upload that file.. the purpose is to have this specific format

Comment: @Vlad Then replace `E:/download.pdf` by `example-image-duck`, say, and make sure your code compiles. (I tried to do these replacements but according to what I find with these replacements alone your code does not compile.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your close interaction. I don't have access to my computer right now, but did you make sure that the image is in pdf format and you tried to compile in nonstop mode twice, as described above? If so maybe you are missing one of the packages..

Comment: @Vlad I tried to do precisely that and get complaints about `dimension too large` errors.

Comment: Hmm.. What happens if you hit Enter when it complains about that? I was getting the same complaints, but non stop mode was just running over them. In the regular compiling mode, pressing enter when the complaints appear would also overcome this issue

Comment: @Vlad I am definitely not going to ignore error messages. The result of the compilation will be random.

Comment: I understand what you mean, it is not a very clean approach, but I've been using this method for quite a while and I can say that the results are not random. I experienced consistency in results

Comment: @Vlad Yes, but please understand that I cannot provide answers containing codes that throw errors. It is not excluded that someone else will provide you with such a code but IMHO you should first make your code run through, either by repairing it yourself or asking a question on it, and then try to fix the other things.

Comment: I understand, Marmot. At some point in the past, running through this error (or compiling in non stop mode) was my solution for getting the format that I wanted, and I had no problem with that since it worked all the time. But I also understand your position. I might open a new thread with how to get the same result without needing to skip through the error then. But I would also like to keep this thread open for now, if that is fine.

Comment: The code has been updated and it is now fully compilable. The Question stays..

Comment: @Vlad No, it does not because it includes some graphics that others do not have. If I replace that graphics file by `example-image-dcuk.pdf`, which is on (more or less) every TeX installation, I get `pdfTeX warning (ext4)
: destination with the same identifier (name{page.}) has been already used, dup
licate ignored`. While this does not cause the compilation to stop, it is still a serious issue.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I can also see that warning. But the pdf gets build without any problem.

Anyway, could you guide me on how I could overcome this warning?

Comment: @Vlad No, I do not. I believe to have provided a clean working solution above. In the past, I had not so nice experiences with `xwatermark`, and it is quite possible that you have discovered yet another murky feature. If you insist on using the commands and packages precisely in the way you are used to do, that's your choice, but I do not see why I should employ all these methods and clean them up just to later discover that there is an issue that I cannot solve.