# Functionality of section titles over pdf images only valid in non stop mode

Tags: compilation-error

UPDATED. The following code is functional, but the pdf only gets generated if Enter key is pressed when warning messages appear. My solution at the moment is to run it in non stop mode, such: open cmd in the proper location and type 'pdflatex -interaction nonstopmode example.tex'. I was wondering if there was any way of obtaining the same results in a clean manner i.e. without needing to push through the warnings.

```
\documentclass[10pt, a3paper]{article}
\newcommand{\projecttitle}{Interaction Nonstopmode}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
a3paper,
left=23mm,
top=15mm,
right=10mm,
bottom=15mm,
headheight=38pt,
includeheadfoot,
showframe=false
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\section{Section 1}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{any_pdf_image.pdf}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\section{Section 2}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{any_pdf_image.pdf}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\section{Section 3}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{any_pdf_image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your problem is not clearly described, as you seem to already have a (the) solution. If  y correctly guess that you would like to avoid to resort to command line, the answer would be to edit the command  line executed for compilation, but this strongly depends of the editor you are using. By the way, none of the tag that you have selected is related to the question you are asking.

Comment: Well the first error is that scale=12 doesn't work. But I really don't want to debug xwatermark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The xwatermark puts the watermark in a \parbox of size \paperwidth/\paperheight. When trying to scale this by 12 and then rotate it, the dimension gets too large. Move the scaling into the savebox.

The second problem is that you are using \section inside a \node. That is quite daring. Hide it in a \parbox:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a3paper]{article}


\newcommand{\projecttitle}{Interaction Nonstopmode}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
a3paper,
left=23mm,
top=15mm,
right=10mm,
bottom=15mm,
headheight=38pt,
includeheadfoot,
showframe=false
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newsavebox\mybox
\savebox\mybox{\scalebox{12}{\tikz[color=gray!1000,opacity=0.3]\node{DRAFT};}}
\newwatermark*[allpages,angle=45]{\usebox\mybox}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents \thispagestyle{fancy}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\parbox{\linewidth}{\section{Section 1}}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{example-image.pdf}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\parbox{\linewidth}{\section{Section 2}}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{example-image.pdf}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\includepdf[scale=1.000, trim=0cm 0cm 0.0cm 2cm, pagecommand= {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] \node [anchor=west] at (-0.2, 0) {\parbox{\linewidth}{\section{Section 3}}}; \end{tikzpicture}}]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I updated the code. No need for that watermark.
@Jhor. The solution is fine for me. The problem is that I posted a different issue, and I have been told that the code needs to be compilable in order to get help

Comment: Did you also see the changes I made to the \section commands?

Comment: That is wonderful! It works!

Comment: Ulrike, you are a genius! The watermark thing worked too! After applying these two corrections, the pdf gets built without any interference. However, do you have any idea why the DRAFT watermark only appears on the first page, even though it is set to all pages? or should I start a different thread about it?

Comment: Ask a new question.

Comment: please allow me to refer you to my original question. I marked this one as answered. thank you
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/480045/watermark-combined-with-no-page-numbering-in-toc

Comment: Hello Ulrike. Would you like to help me with the above issue? I am asking because you seem very good at \newwatermark, and people are still complaining about some warnings that the compilation returns, even though no errors occur

Comment: @Vlad sorry not today. I'm busy.

Comment: Hello Ulrike. I solved the problem by using 'background' package. Thank you again for your help